# What to look for in a rifle bipod?

Tags: guns, shooting, target-shooting, rifles

I am planning on getting a bipod for my rifle, in the hope of being more accurate and able to hit targets at longer ranges.

What features should I look for in a rifle bipod?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is important to match your intended shooting height to the bipod that you select. Additionally, the longer that you are shooting the more stable the attachment between the rifle and the bipod need to be. Additionally to properly load up the bipod you want feet that will grip the surface that you are on instead of allowing the bipod to walk forward.